# Jquery/javascript not working on node js project

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Hi im new to Node JS and programming in general. Im working on a small project where there is an admin page for different user. and Im using a admin template called matrix Admin.

Everything seems to be working ok except for Javascript and Jquery in general. Im not sure where the root cause of the problem is but it seems to me that the the jquery files and js files were not loading.

here is the middleware that i use for the public folders where all my files are located including JS files and its working because the CSS is being rendered.

```
const p = app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Here is the filepath of all the js files on my public folder

```
 <script src="/public/js/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/jquery.ui.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
```

There might be some conflict that prohibits them from loading im not sure what it is
here is my package.json file

```
 "dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"mongoose": "^5.0.6",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0"
```

}

Here is my file structure
my project

my project

```
|-- node_module
|-- config
|-- models
|-- public
    |   |-- css
    |   |-- img
    |   `-- js
| -- app.js
```

Comment: Your middleware already adds the /public path. If your JS files are in the public folder src should be just "/js/..." and not "/public/js/..."

Comment: Can you show your file structure?

Comment: hi james ive added my file structure

Comment: @EndaMolloy hi ive already tried removing the public but still the same thing

Answer (score -1):

Ive managed to solve my issue there was a js file conflict on the plethora of js plugins that i included. did a trial and error approach very time consuming but was able to solve the issue.